# Handling Multiple UIImageViews Together

Tags: uiimageview, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10

I have UIImageViews in three different view controllers displaying the same thing, that being user's profile pic. I want them all to update at the same time when the user changes his/her profile pic using imagepickercontroller. I thought about outlet collection, but I believe they don't work across different view controllers. I am out of ideas on this one, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are few solutions for your problem. One of them is using your profile image as global variable. Then whenever you move to a viewcontroller, in their viewWillAppear, assign the profile image to the UIImageViews.

It's simple, isn't it?